Configure Apache httpd to host app with domain and avoid port conflict
I am deploying a React (UI) / Python (backend) application running on port 3001 to a GoDaddy-reserved domain (www.demo.com) with TLS on an Apache (httpd) server within a AWS Amazon Linux 2023 EC2 instance using this. Docker compose runs the app within EC2 using a static elastic IP. Without httpd or TLS, the app runs fine navigating to elasticIP:3001. But once I configure httpd & TLS, I navigate to https://www.demo.com and all I get is the "It works!" Apache success page (this shows that TLS is working).
I found posts that talk about updating the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 'Listen' property and/or creating the VirtualHost directive, but I'm confused...if I add an httpd.conf 'Listen 3001' property, I get a port conflict when I start the app because the new property tells Apache what ports to listen/run on, so that conflicts with my app's port.
For the VirtualHost piece, I tried the below and it returned the same Apache success page on navigation to https://www.demo.com.
  <VirtualHost *:3001>
      ServerName www.demo.com
  </VirtualHost>

Questions:

How do I configure Apache to connect to my app's port 3001 on https://www.demo.com without a port conflict? Or port 80? The app can run on 80
Do I need a DocumentRoot or some other VirtualHost property? The docs show the below example, but where does that path come from/exist? Does VirtualHost go in httpd.conf?

   DocumentRoot "/www/docs/host.example.com"

UPDATE with TLS/SSL implementation steps
# Here are the instructions from the second link (AWS doc) from my question summarized. I currently run these manually after spinning up the EC2 and installing docker, compose, git repos:

sudo service httpd start
sudo service httpd status
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y mod_ssl
sudo service httpd restart

# Custom key in /etc/pki/tls/private
cd /etc/pki/tls/private
sudo openssl genrsa -out custom.key
sudo chown root.root custom.key
sudo chmod 600 custom.key

cd /etc/pki/tls/private
sudo openssl req -new -key custom.key -out csr.pem
________________________
# Submit the CSR to a CA (godaddy in my case; essentially I rekey the cert with a new csr, wait for approval, then download new crt file)
  download cert files
________________________
# Place the new CA-signed certificate and any intermediate certificates in the /etc/pki/tls/certs
cd /etc/pki/tls/certs
sudo vi custom.crt
paste crt file contents downloaded from godaddy (above)
sudo chown root.root custom.crt
sudo chmod 600 custom.crt
cd /etc/pki/tls/private
sudo rm /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
________________________
# Edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf to reflect your new certificate and key files.
Provide the path and file name of the CA-signed host certificate in Apache's SSLCertificateFile directive:
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/custom.crt
# I did not do this second step; from godaddy I received a crt and pem (these are same file/contents, and a abc-bundle.crt which I do not use)
If you received an intermediate certificate file 
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
Provide the path and file name of the private key in Apache's SSLCertificateKeyFile directive:
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/custom.key
________________________
8. Save /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and restart Apache.
sudo service httpd restart
Navigate to URL with https



Your app needs to run on port 3001, and Apache needs to run on port 80. Apache needs to be configured as a reverse proxy to send any traffic to the app running on port 3001.
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
</VirtualHost>

This way when an HTTP request comes in on the default HTTP port (80), for the domain www.demo.com, Apache passes that request along to your application, and returns the response from your application.

I replaced your 'localhost' above with my elasticIP and the app displayed on port 80, i.e., not specifying a port of course, so great!

...but implementing TLS got me the same Apache success page only, not my app. For that I changed my elasticIP to www.demo.com in both proxy entries (where localhost was originally) and for ServerName. Is that what I should have done?

...and was I correct to place the VirtualHost entry in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf? Update: well since the initial change worked, I guess so?

Is apache not running on the same server as your application? If so, it needs to be localhost not your elastic IP. Otherwise Apache is going out to the Internet and back to access something that is already running on the same server Apache is on.

'same server'? It is, so let me try localhost

You haven't shown anything about how you have configured TLS, so I have no idea how to help you there. Edit your question to add that information if you want help with getting SSL/TLS to work.

I just updated the question with my TLS/SSL steps. I was going to post it here but it would've been a mess

I haven't used Apache in years, I find Nginx to be far better, but I think you have a separate VirtualHost configuration for port 443 for your SSL/TLS configuration, and you need to have the same reverse proxy values in there that you have in the port 80 VirtualHost configuration. I was asking to see the SSL, port 443 configuration portion of your httpd.conf file, not your notes on how you put TLS certificate files on your server.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
